# Telnet - getting closed automatically when trying to connect to a peer in hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, telnet

I have setup an hyperledger fabric network with 6 organizations and 5 orderers (raft consensus). Each org has 2 peers. All the peers are running in 7051 ports and orderers in 7050 port.
When I try to do telnet to the peers,

```
telnet <ip> 7051
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But the telnet connection is automatically getting closed after 3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Few Suggestions:

1. check the `ports` are opened or not in the firewall.
2. If the ports are opened and `source` is set to specific IP then try changing it to `0.0.0.0`. `0.0.0.0` is for testing only.
3. Also try `nc -vz IP port` command. Is is same as telnet.
4. Make sure containers are running fine on server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried allowing 0.0.0.0/0 and tested. It is closing after 2-3 seconds. Is this any limitation of peer and orderer service in blockchain network. And the peer service is in running state, because when I try to do telnet, it is getting connected for about 2-3 seconds. Can you suggest further. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the ports? Can you try `nc -vz  Instance_Ip 7050`?

Comment: On using the commands, nc -vz <ip> 7051, The result is "Connection to 10.205.1.242 7051 port [tcp/*] succeeded!"

Comment: Then it means everything is fine. Nothing wrong with firewall settings. Any specific reason for doing telnet. Also , don't put your public IP in the comments, string `Connection to 10.205.X.X`.

Comment: `Connection closed by foreign host` means the process that is listening for connections on port 7051 is accepting the connection and then immediately closing the connection. So this is related to peer configuration. Can you please share your `compose.yaml` files?

Comment: Ok , I am attaching core.yaml file which is used to start the peer. Please find the core.yaml in the link: https://github.com/SoundaryaA3098/k8s_problem_statement/blob/master/core.yaml. And please suggest me asap! Thanks in advance

Comment: I have provided the peer configuration yaml file in the github. Additionally, I have a doubt, my network is TLS enabled. Is that may be the reason for the telnet to the peer is getting ended after few seconds.?

Comment: yes, telnet won't work with tls enabled. It doesn't work with `https`. Instead use `openssl s_client -connect IP Port`.

Comment: As a result of openssl command, I am getting - "SSL handshake has read 1881 bytes and written 281 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate" and it is getting closed after providing the following line "read:errno=0". Can you give update on this?

Comment: can you add complete openssl result to your question?

Comment: Sure, Please find the complete openssl result in the attached link: https://github.com/SoundaryaA3098/k8s_problem_statement/blob/master/openssl.txt

Comment: add `-CAfile tlsca.pem` to `openssl` command and try. `tlsca.pem` is a certificate with `CN=tlsca.originator.abc.def.com`. so try to run inside container if not present on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the pem certificate which belongs to tlsca.originator.abc.def.com. Please find the result of the command in the link: https://github.com/SoundaryaA3098/k8s_problem_statement/blob/master/Openssl.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217061/discussion-between-soundarya-and-alpha).

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you guide me further.